# New line character

Tags: blob, newline, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to load the data into snowflake. My source is Oracle DB. I'm creating CSV files into multiple chunks and uploading it into azure BLOB. From Azure Blob to snowflake. In DB it has the data of text for CLOB data type columns. I'm using '\n' as a row separator in BDM, and I'm replacing '\n' with empty quotes. So, I can able to load the data into CSV files. The challenge here I'm facing is, I'm getting the data into a single row of a particular column. But I need the data looks like in multiple row as it is in the DB.

Comment: Could you provide a sample string that you have?  If you are removing the \n, then you won't have multiple rows of text in the DB.  So, you either need to maintain the \n by escaping it in the text (\\n, for example), or replace it with a strange character that you can then replace in Snowflake after it is loaded.

Comment: Agreed. With file formats, you can specify any delimiter you'd like and then escape special characters as needed.